# how do I check that CNN model correctly implemented or not?

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

How do I make it confirm that the dropout model function parameter is correct or not?

Here, I have coded a CNN architecture but I am not able to confirm that architecture correctly implemented or not? how do I confirm it. The input images dimension is 88x128 which has been taken from a research paper (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7550060).

I am following architecture and parameters present in attached figure.

Architectural diagram and parametric table

[image: architectural diagram and parametric table]

The textual information is present into this figure:

(textual information's)

[image: textual information's]

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
batch_size = 4
num_classes = 35
epochs = 40
#178, 256, 1
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(128, 88, 1), kernel_size=(18, 18), strides=1, activation='relu', padding='valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(45, 45), strides=1, activation='relu', padding='valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reproduce the paper's result. If the results are not the same (or different by a huge margin), then, you should consider your implementation as incorrect.

Comment: May you verify this code? Is it similar to given architecture in the image files?

Comment: The number of filters is not 96, it should be 18, 45 respectively. Also, kernel_size should be (7,7), and (5,5). Dropout probability is speculative but it is possible. Normalization strategy seems wrong according to the paper. I'm not sure if you should use Local response normalization instead or not.